# run pycharm pro in docker

Tags: docker, pycharm

I want to use a docker container for running the pycharm pro software.

I can install pycharm on my host (archlinux) pc directly.

But I want to use docker container for it.

Also the pro version of pycharm has a 30 days free limit. So if i destroy the container, will that 30 days free limit get extended.

Will using docker break these softwares free pro time limit constraints

I think rebuilding the image may break the free pro time limit constraints.

Any thoughts on this

Comment: Docker is an isolated instance so you can deploy and destroy image without affecting license. The question, does that interferes with license agreement of JetBrain? The other part of question how to dockerize pycharm pro, not sure about.

Comment: What have you already tried?  What problems are you running into?  In general GUIs and IDEs are not a good match for Docker containers: running graphical applications requires a complex and platform-specific setup, and an IDE in a container won't be able to access your host files.  The licensing question doesn't really seem like a programming-related question that would be on-topic here.